Sound issues on HP x360 2-in-1 15-ew1xxx
I'm currently running Ubuntu 24.04.1 with linux kernel 6.10.7. Since I switched my laptop to Ubuntu it's had problems with sound coming out of the built-in speakers. When I was on Ubuntu 22, no sound worked at all and I did a bunch of research and saw it was a problem specific to HP and the current kernel. So I waited until Ubuntu 24 came out and installed it right away, sound still didn't work. So I upgraded from the 6.8 kernel to the 6.10 kernel. This got some of my speakers working. The front two under the laptop work but the two on top, next to the keyboard, still don't. I'm not sure what else to try as all the other discussions I've found are about patching older kernels or upgrading to different kernels that I've already upgraded past. I've included some info about my system and can provide anything else that could be helpful. Any help to get my top speakers working would be great.
$ uname -r
6.10.7-061007-generic

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble

$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC245 Analog [ALC245 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

$ sudo dmesg | grep sound
[    7.136171] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input39
[    7.136343] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input40
[    7.136452] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input41
[    7.136575] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input42
[    7.136675] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input43
[    7.136774] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input44

$ lsmod | grep sound
soundwire_intel        73728  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_generic
soundwire_cadence      45056  1 soundwire_intel
snd_sof_intel_hda_mlink    45056  3 soundwire_intel,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_hda_generic
soundwire_generic_allocation    12288  1 soundwire_intel
soundwire_bus         114688  3 soundwire_intel,soundwire_generic_allocation,soundwire_cadence
snd_soc_core          446464  6 snd_soc_avs,snd_soc_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_pcm               196608  12 snd_soc_avs,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_sof_utils,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
soundcore              16384  1 snd



have you checked with alsamixer that the top speakers are not muted?

You might have more luck with "pipewire" - the successor of pulseaudio. I have described it here

At the present time no version of Ubuntu supports the 6.10 kernel.
